# C++ casting int into enum then read that enum as bit field safe or not?

Tags: c++, serialization, enums, union, undefined-behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

enum class OrderFlags : uint16_t {
  None = 0,
  BuySide = 1,
  UpdateVolume = 2,
  UpdatePrice = 4,
  Market = 8,
  Float = 16,
  Aggressive = 32,
};

struct OrderFlagsBitField {
  uint8_t side : 1;
  uint8_t update_volume : 1;
  uint8_t update_price : 1;
  uint8_t market_order : 1;
  uint8_t float_order : 1;
  uint8_t aggressive : 1;
  uint16_t reserved : 10;
};
static_assert(sizeof(OrderFlagsBitField) == 2);

struct Order {
    int order_id;
    union {
        OrderFlags flags;
        OrderFlagsBitField flags_bf;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Order order1;
    order1.order_id = 123;
    uint16_t value = 1 + 2 + 8 + 32;
    memcpy(&order1.flags, &value, sizeof(value));

    Order order2 = order1;
    cout << int(order2.flags_bf.side) << " " << int(order2.flags_bf.update_volume) << " " << int(order2.flags_bf.update_price) << " "
         << int(order2.flags_bf.market_order) << " " << int(order2.flags_bf.float_order) << " " << int(order2.flags_bf.aggressive) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have a code like above. `value` represents a flag that can contain multiple `OrderFlags` value. Basically, I want to serialize a `uint16_t` into a `Order` object with this union.

Is this code safe or not? For this case, the output should be `1 1 0 1 0 1`, even if I write `order1` object into a file, then read-as-byte from that file again into `order2`.

Comment: Compiler vendors are free to choose _where_ the bits are placed. I don't think the C++ standard gives any guarantee that `side` should correspond to bit 0 of the structure. Note that the only benefit in your approach is _convenience_, at the sacrifice of portability (if not correctness). And I believe (although I'd need to check the standard) that even your struct padding is not guaranteed because your 10-bit `uint16_t` overlaps a boundary of what's entirely `uint8_t` bit fields appearing before it. What is wrong with using predictable bitwise operations for your flags?

Comment: Pretty much completely implementation-defined.

Comment: But `OrderFlags flags;` in the union serves no purpose. `memcpy(&order1.flags_bf, &value, sizeof(value));` would do exactly the same thing, but would at least get rid of any doubt about aliasing violations or active union member issues without presence of `flags`. In particular trying to access _both_ `flags` and `flags_bf` in the same object will be UB in C++ (but not C).

Comment: This code with be safe if you regard to [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @paddy `What's wrong with using bitwise ops for your flags` nothing actually, this code just looks shorter. But idk if it's incorrect or not

Comment: @user17732522 the structs are from legacy code, so I can't change that directly. That's why they look like that.

Comment: It looks sketchy as heck to me. I would avoid doing stuff like that if you can. You're using C++. You can encapsulate your flag-tests as member functions, or even a type-safe read/write accessor, all while maintaining an underlying set of flags stored in a `uint16_t` that doesn't make you read the C++ standard to figure out if it's okay or not. When you're asking yourself those kinds of questions, you gotta take a step back and decide how you might feel about maintaining that code 2 years from now.

Comment: Even in C, in industrial code standards like MISRA, unions and bit field usage are prohibited for safety and portability issues. If you want to use those features in your code and your code will work at multiple platforms (OS, compilers, architecture) you should at least test them at those platforms.

Comment: I recommend reviewing the section of [ask] titled "Introduce the problem before you post any code".

Comment: For C++ [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is a more preferred mechanism for working with an array of bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined behavior. Handle each flag in the bit field instead. Such as:

```
int bf2int(BitFieldFlag flag)
{
  int res = 0;
  if (flag.attribute1) res |= 1 << 0;
  if (flag.attribute2) res |= 1 << 1;
  // ...
  return res;
}

void int2bf(BitFieldFlag &flag, int flag_int)
{
  memset(&flag, 0, sizeof(flag));
  if ((flag_int >> 0) & 1) flag.attribute1 = 1;
  if ((flag_int >> 1) & 1) flag.attribute2 = 1;
  // ...
}
```